# Why does ajax call give parsererror with a lot of records

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have several areas worth of data ranging from 30 objects to 1,000 objects.  When the array contents is less than 400 it works, but if it exceeds that, I will get a parsererror.  I've tried removing changing and removing the datatype, but that returns a null / "" value.  Added an HTTPPOST header to the mvc method, but still nothing.

**JavaScript:**

```
function loadPatentListFromServer(sites, teams, users) {
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#workingIconContainer') });

    var requestData =
    {
        sites: sites,
        teams: teams,
        users: users,
        dFilter: dFilter,
        hfilter: hfilter
    };

    jQuery.ajax(
        {
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json ; charset=utf-8",
            converters: Utills.jQueryAjaxJsondDataConverter,
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            dataType: "jsond",
            type: "POST",
            url: _GET_REMOVE_TO_BIN_PATIENTS_SERVICE_URL,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Nothing
                var checkTheError = null;
                $.unblockUI();
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                _unfilteredList = data;
```

**Controller method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult GetObjects(FooRecord FooRecord)
{
   //FooRecord FooRecord = new FooRecord();
    List<RemoverGridPatientRecord> viewModelData = LoadPatientListFromServer(FooRecord.sites, FooRecord.teams, FooRecord.users, FooRecord.dischargeFilter, FooRecord.hasnobillsfilter);

   var viewModelObjs = viewModelData.Select(r => new RemovetoBinModel
   {
            Id = r.Id as string,
            LastName = r.LastName as string,
            FirstName = r.FirstName as string,
            Di = r.Di as string,
            DiDate = r.DiDate as string,
            Ho = r.Ho as string,
            Team = r.Team as string,
            Patent = r.Patent as string,
            Missing = r.Missing as string,
            HasBi = r.HasBi as string
    }).OrderBy(x => x.LastName + x.FirstName).ToList();

    return Json(viewModelObjs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class FooRecord
{
    public List<string> sites { get; set; }
    public List<string> teams { get; set; }
    public List<string> users { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is reporting the error? If it's a parse error, have you examined the data you are attempting to parse? How is 400 results different from 399 results?

Comment: `async: false`? It blocks your event loop! You should REALLY refactor your code to use callbacks instead.

Comment: I'll bet it's a bug in your custom converter Utills.jQueryAjaxJsondDataConverter. Does the crash come from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may be due to the `maxJsonLength` property where its default value is 102400(100k). Please add the following method in your controller to set the `maxJsonLength` to the max value of int.

```
protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonResult()
    {
       Data = data,
       ContentType = contentType,
       ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
       JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
       MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
    };
}
```